# invalid TOML syntax

Tags: configuration

I am trying to run influxDB relay service with the following configuration file:

```
/# -*- toml -*-

[[http]] 
name = example-http-influxdb 
bind-addr = 0.0.0.0:8086

[[http.output]] 
name = local-influxdb01 
location = http://192.168.1.15:8086/ 
endpoints = {write=/write, write_prom=/api/v1/prom/write, ping=/ping, query=/query} 
timeout = 10s

\# EOF
```

But I get the follwing erro:

> line 1: invalid TOML syntax

I wonder what is wrong with the above syntax ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert on the specific problem of influxDB, but a comment in TOML is just a diesis `#`, without slash or anti slash in front of it, as you can see in the [README](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml#user-content-comment).

So, try it with

```
# -*- toml -*-

[[http]]
name = "example-http-influxdb"
bind-addr = "0.0.0.0:8086"

[[http.output]]
name = "local-influxdb01"
location = "http://192.168.1.15:8086/"
endpoints = {write="/write", write_prom="/api/v1/prom/write", ping="/ping", query="/query"} 
timeout = "10s"

# EOF
```

Also, please not what a the brackets mean, they are [Array of tables](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml#user-content-array-of-tables).

Comment: Thank you again, I've solved it (I got it from the readme file you pointed me to)